# bootstrap 3.0.3 inline form: label, 4 textboxes, button

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, inline

With the new bootstrap, you can't set textbox lenght, so I'm wondering how I can code the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGoUK.png

It should be so smart and simple as possible.

Comment: here: http://bootply.com/102053#

Answer (score 0):

You'd use the form-inline and the form-groups (clean up the html, add your sr-only labels for your situation):

```
<form class="form-inline my-form-inline" role="form">

<label>Test&nbsp;</label>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">
</div>
-
<div class="form-group">
<label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
</div>
-
<div class="form-group">
<label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
</div>
-
<div class="form-group">
<label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>

</div>
```

Then adjust the css (you will need to adjust):

```
.my-form-inline .form-group {display:inline-block!important;}
.my-form-inline .form-control {width:100%;display:inline-block!important;}


@media (min-width:500px) {

.my-form-inline .form-group {display:inline-block!important;}
.my-form-inline .form-control {width:80px;display:inline-block!important;}

}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/OGoZUye/1/edit